# How to call web API on behalf of a signed in user outside of controllers in c#

Tags: azure, authentication, impersonation

I have a client (web application or desktop app) that signs in a user and calls another web APIs on behalf of the signed-in user. According to the instruction in "https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/scenario-web-app-call-api-overview", the API calls must be done in a controller. That is not possible with a pure web application or a desktop client. Using a public client does not work either because in our case multifactor authentication is required. Does anyone have a solution to this problem?

Comment: How does the Web API authenticates the signed-in user ?
I have used Http Client from a desktop app to call APIs by passing the required authentication parameters to the API method.

Comment: I use azure authorization attributes together with some settings in the web service (see "https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/scenario-web-app-sign-user-overview?tabs=aspnetcore"). The scenario here is that the web app does not have direct access to a user's credential, but acts on behalf of that user.